# Linux Mint 17.1: startx doesn't work and startxfce4 requires root

Tags: command-line, xfce

On Linux Mint 17.1 with XFCE installed, I removed MDM to enable booting in text mode. Now, when I try to run `startx`, it open the xfce4-panels on a grey background but gets stuck there with the panels not responding. Same happens with running `startxfce4` (it also loads the wallpaper). `sudo startxfce4` does works perfectly but it logs me in the graphical mode as root.

Is there any way to start the XFCE GUI manually using an unprivileged account?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
# cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc  /home/user/.config/xfce4/xinitrc
# chown user /home/user/.config/xfce4/xinitrc
# chown user /home/user/.ICEauthority
$ startxfce4
```